# Lag() to get what a value changes to snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions, lag, gaps-and-islands

I have a table that has data that looks like:

| ID | NAME | DATE | ORDER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | MICHELLE | 2023-01-01 | 2 |
| 15 | MICHELLE | 2023-01-04 | 3 |
| 15 | MITCH | 2023-01-15 | 7 |

(this is a small sample of my table data for a specific id)

I would like to get a table the gives back the ID, and what the value was at a specific point in time/ what it changed to

For example, I would like my table to look like

| ID | NAME | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | MICHELLE | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-15 |
| 15 | MITCH | 2023-01-15 | 2023-03-10 |

Where for the last value given an id, its TO_DATE would be the current date.

I've done

```
SELECT ID, 
       LAG(NAME) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ORDER) AS NAME,
       LAG(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, ORDER BY ORDER) AS FROM_DATE, 
       DATE AS TO_DATE
FROM MY_TABLE
```

However this is returning

| ID | NAME | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | MICHELLE | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-04 |
| 15 | MICHELLE | 2023-01-04 | 2023-01-15 |

Rather than just putting MICHELLE into one row since there is no change from 2023-01-01 to 2023-01-15 and I am unable to show that the name has changed from MICHELLE to MITCH and that change has continued until today's date (since there is not record that comes after it)

Is there a way I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you intend for Michelle and Mitch to have the same ID? They're both 15.

Comment: Yep I want to see the changes in name within an id group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the lead window function on the min(DATE) aggregate like this:

```
select ID, NAME, min(DATE) as FROM_DATE
      ,lead(FROM_DATE, 1, current_date) 
         over (partition by ID order by FROM_DATE) as TO_DATE
from MY_TABLE
group by ID, NAME;
```

Here's a self-contained sample:

```
with MY_TABLE as
    (
    select 
    COLUMN1::int as "ID",
    COLUMN2::string as "NAME",
    COLUMN3::date as "DATE",
    COLUMN4::int as "ORDER"
    from (values
    ('15','MICHELLE','2023-01-01','2'),
    ('15','MICHELLE','2023-01-04','3'),
    ('15','MITCH','2023-01-15','7')
    )
)
select ID, NAME, min(DATE) as FROM_DATE, lead(FROM_DATE, 1, current_date) over (partition by ID order by FROM_DATE) as TO_DATE
from MY_TABLE
group by ID, NAME;
```

Edit: If the names can change back to the names they were before with the same ID, here's an example with more test data and updated solution for that. It uses the conditional_change_event function to form new groups. It sorts the dates descending to make it easy to know which rows are at the end and need to be change to the current_date:

```
with MY_TABLE as
    (
    select 
    COLUMN1::int as "ID",
    COLUMN2::string as "NAME",
    COLUMN3::date as "DATE",
    COLUMN4::int as "ORDER"
    from (values
    ('15','MICHELLE','2023-01-01','2'),
    ('15','MICHELLE','2023-01-04','3'),
    ('15','MICHELLE','2023-01-05','4'),
    ('15','MITCH',   '2023-01-15','7'),
    ('15','MICHELLE','2023-02-04','9'),
    ('16','BOB','2023-01-01','8')
    )
)
select   ID
        ,NAME
        ,min("DATE") as START_DATE
        ,iff(NAME_CHANGE = 0, current_date, max("DATE")) as END_DATE
from (
    select    *
        ,conditional_change_event("NAME") over (partition by ID order by "DATE" desc) NAME_CHANGE 
    from     MY_TABLE
)
group by ID, NAME, NAME_CHANGE
order by ID, START_DATE
;
```

| ID | NAME | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | MICHELLE | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-01-05 |
| 15 | MITCH | 2023-01-15 00:00:00 | 2023-01-15 |
| 15 | MICHELLE | 2023-02-04 00:00:00 | 2023-03-11 |
| 16 | BOB | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-03-11 |

Comment: Yes, but this does not handle the case when a name is reused later on. If you add another row at the end of the dataset with name Michelle and a further date, the query still returns 2 rows, while 3 rows would maybe make more sense…

Comment: Updated to handle the name changing back to a previous value within the same ID.

Comment: Looks good now!

Answer (score 2):

If I read this correctly, you can use `lead()` twice:

```
select id, name, 
    date as from_date, 
    lead(date, 1, current_date) over(partition by id order by ord) as to_date
from (
    select t.*, lead(name) over(partition by id order by ord) as lead_name
    from mytable t
) t
where name is distinct from lead_name
order by id, ord
```

The subquery retrieves the "next" name of the same id ; we can then use this information to filter out rows that do not correspond to a name change, and finally use `lead()` again to retrieve the relevant end date.

Comment: The where clause should be `where lead_name is distinct from name` and the lead function needs `lead(date, 1, current_date)` to use the current_date instead of returning null for the last date in each window.